# Viewing Old iOS App Function

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

I have an old photo editing 32-bit iOS app from around 2013/14. It no longer works on iOS since the transition to 64-bit but I wondered if there was a way to look into the apps code to discover some of the photo editing settings? There’s a few photo filters I would love to replicate in Photoshop.

Comment: If the app is discontinued you could try to contact the author and ask. Reverse engineering the app is very hard and will consume much time (I would expect several hundred hours unless you are an reverse engineering expert).